# lambda layer using colander

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I'm trying to create a colander layer from AWS Lambda Functions but unable to do so. I have created the python zip file containing the unpack wheel file from [PyPI-colander](https://pypi.org/project/colander/) and then uploading it to as a file but the response is `"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'colander'"`

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the python documentation [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-python-package-compatible/).  In particular make sure you are downloading a binary that matches the environment you are choosing for your lambda (e.g. x86_64 or arm64).  Also note the directory path of the target inside the zip -> /python/lib/python3.9/site-packages.

You can also deploy that package/zip as a layer, if you plan on reusing it across lambda functions.